# 'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a return-type annotation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

The first snippet is the code im working with and below is the error it throws and it happens on every "yield select" portion that is in the code and im not sure what my next step is.

```
function* onLoadingDomainsresult() {
  const pathname = yield select(getPathname);

  interface Params {
    hastag: string;
  }

'yield' expression implicitly results in an 'any' type because its containing generator lacks a return-type annotation.  TS7057

    113 | 
    114 | function* onLoadingDomainsresult() {
  > 115 |   const pathname = yield select(getPathname);
        |                    ^
    116 | 
    117 |   interface Params {
    118 |     hastag: string;
```

Comment: What is the return value of `select(getPathname)`?

Comment: I don't know if it has one. I went looking for it and couldn't find anything. This code was handed down to me yesterday. I'm just trying to get it working on my machine

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The literal type of `select(getPathname)` doesn't relate to the value you get back from the `yield`. `select(getPathname)` is the value yielded by your co-routine to its iterating context.

The value injected into your generator by its running context (through the `next()` call) DOES matter to the type you get back from the `yield` expression.

Either way, currently Typescript has no metadata about what it's going to get at all, since your generator function has no type annotation.

I'm guessing this is redux-saga.

A typical Generator function type annotation is something like...

```
type WhatYouYield="foo"
type WhatYouReturn="bar"
type WhatYouAccept="baz"

function* myfun(): Generator<
  WhatYouYield,
  WhatYouReturn,
  WhatYouAccept
> {
const myYield = "foo" //type of myYield is WhatYouYield
const myAccepted = yield myYield; //type of myAccepted is WhatYouAccept
return "baz" //type of this value is WhatYouReturn 
}
```

...and the error you're getting is from Typescript having to guess the `WhatYouAccept` type without the Generator type annotation on your function.

Comment: thank you, breaking that down for me really helped!

Comment: Having said all that, redux-saga is well known for being a pain with Typescript because generators as a whole have to declare their accepted + yielded types once, even though with redux-saga wants to serve you a different type each time, depending what effect you yielded. There is a workaround which is to use a delegating yield and annotate that with typing information - the return value can be typed differently from the yield+accept.

Answer (score 27):

I got same error and I solved it.

```
export interface ResponseGenerator{
    config?:any,
    data?:any,
    headers?:any,
    request?:any,
    status?:number,
    statusText?:string
}
```

```
const response:ResponseGenerator = yield YOUR_YIELD_FUNCTION
console.log(response.data)
```

Comment: When I tried to specify export function* MyFunction(): ResponseGenerator {
                      yield put(dialogAction) };
I've got 
Type 'Generator<any, any, any>' has no properties in common with type 'ResponseGenerator'.ts(2559)

Comment: it's a simple and good idea, thank you.

Answer (score 15):

In recent updates of typescript, there are more type restrictions on generator functions.

**Type 1: yield with call**

```
function* initDashboard(): any {
  let response = yield call(getDashboardData);
  console.log(response);
}
```

**Type 2: yield without call**

```
function* initDashboard() {
  let response: any = yield getDashboardData;
  console.log(response);
}
```

**Note:** Using `any` is fastest solution but proper solution would be creating type/interface for the response and using it as type.

Answer (score 6):

You could add any as return type

```
function* onLoadingDomainsresult():any {
  const pathname = yield select(getPathname);

  interface Params {
    hastag: string;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by adding "any" as return type to the function signatures.

```
114 | function* onLoadingDomainsresult() : any {
115 |   const pathname = yield select(getPathname);
```