# Is it possible to have strong TypeScript typings for redux-saga?

Tags: typescript, redux-saga

I'd like to have strong types for my Redux sagas. For instance:

```js
// Selector
const getCount = (state: AppState) => state.count;

function* mySaga() {
    // I would like `count` to be typed as `AppState['count']`
    const count = yield select(getCount);
}
```

However, I'm not sure this is possible, because TypeScript is limited to a single `TNext` value. It has no way of knowing what `TNext` value `redux-saga` will provide in a given iteration. Is that right?

[Related Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66922707/147601)

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAgmYGVgENjQLxQN5QMYHsBXAO2AC4pjCBbAIwgCcBuS5aiCgZ2AYEtiA5iwC+TAFBiCxblAERgAYSKkomABTdUHWPCRaAlKoB8UTWgB0BEsHFSZc4ADk2GKBpRoKcRB4iH0JmYQ5sQu4mIA9BFQAJKcULzAUGD4nJy8tAA20MD4UAAWyABu0AIMEKhQoGD8AlAAZvgMUOUAJoQAHgC0nMgCyLIQxIyoTZwA-BL1JLjAvPjEAFSDxADqDMjwjAAMaoZYYlBHUFFQACr5vPECvCXxyMRQjAxN5ofHdklWKpggvBCZVqmAEQWZqBxKaz6cTHPALGShdiqKB-AFAzggsEOZzsaFiYQSU7eF7IXD5KAARgoABFQZlkOUoAMAOJDEa5ZrVaAAd3yjGgAAMzo4IB1gAKEvFgHymZk0AxQmgoPh6lBeZUHiBgdlZk1ZLcIPEQEQ3tNiLN5ksVutNpAGBS9hRWcMNhyADwITHAACi9XqoOAABooEV8LxWsGAEryQgKs7gCBurkqwaKZRJAA+VQTKexLiMJgOsNOFyuTPgJLJUHYDylhSSAu+4uDjWaorYYGywe5vEymSg9CgAu4fEEUCzVDojAFb1hnzh1mRqMB2oD4PkkNIeLn8KSiNcy-RXvXThceIJkWixPwpPJACYKABZB6EZB9rUPYj4Xyy-vC0VJEUb6EIapozHMCzLHIawbFsDB3ns2DvEc85NhQ0bALGxDxpASY5qqELpiYvz-CuGI6sAJ6bsA24fLurDsOhMZxgmeGQLm8g4hAxEoqRR4USeXF4shJzRBc-IAOTxF+0q1FUeTcPgYAokQDQvNQTLEDJqByfwBAMOUsyZCAs50dIe4uA+2AENQnbyACIAUBJ-BAZk4bZpAEnCEufGrlinFnuIF4RIsiyHMsABi6mUPgrQQAA+tQsWENknARAAAm0nQ9H0yARPpEARFyaXAJwADM5gAGwRBAfoBpw5itOYpWaUC5T0mgQL1L2hpQOFERiPw8r1KS0C+v6sxumcyKasGAAKM3ECAhbvBJ6WZRA7TdL0-QRDEADyEkUDwIHvDZtD8KMDAULQ+D4NkDzvFyFBnO8YDICAmQ3q0FBzfiEhDYwI24NACC8LZ2TjQGU3zYty1PGKQytPEUOTWc80rSh+B0JdHIUCNmQYv9gMMMDoNeqjwC0pwuB8GAHJIUc5EBk07haBQs1QOY3MMgInAc0tADaAC6+gCyA7y8-zmkgCL-1clAnoUZTyJgxDECU26EkIN6AAy3oKGcEnBkrAaU9TtO8PTTRGGICtnMgvZurrCNoMQyMyyLPFqGo3PmJkFC6-4JiaoYAFI-EPv5OLwZ++QCTEP6zRnMHMuGOM5xQBQwwlAwYhxbg9KMmaFoLH5wBuhFjzh+7kdBDHXM8wwfPiyLqeakYagiczurXVAVeBiJftSy9juZG6c0Mi48qcJXxAFmIYuKxTdWzJEoXhVA3ru1AG1bTlu0FXCpBDMA-VAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did an investigation for another similar stackoverflow question and unfortunately right now TypeScript doesn't have a great support for libraries using generators as coroutines.

See: [Redux-saga Module augumentation for select effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69381713/redux-saga-module-augumentation-for-select-effect/70038921#70038921)